# POST http calls not working in Ionic iOS build

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I've made an application in Ionic V4 and then build the same using `cordova` plugin (not capacitor). First page of my application is login where I'm getting values from form fields and sending it to login method where I am making a `POST` call to server.

```
loginUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/login';
errorLog: any;

login(form) {
   const user = form.values;
   this.httpClient.post(this.loginUrl, user).subscribe( response => {
      this.toastController.create({message:'Login Successful', duration: 1000}).then(toast=> toast.present());
   }, error => {
      this.errorLog = error;
      this.toastController.create({message:'Some Error Occured', duration: 1000}).then(toast=> toast.present());
   })
}
```

Also I'm printing that error log in login page because once we make build, its hard to debug in device using Android Studio or `Xcode`.

So I'm printing error log like this

```
<h3>{{errorLog | json}}</h3>
```

I'm not getting error from `POST` call in case of running the application in web browser as well as in android. Getting error in iOS when I tried to make build and using `Xcode`, deployed into my iPad.

It's working fine in `GET HTTP` calls because previously I've tested `GET HTTP` calls in same but not working in `POST HTTP` calls.

Its returning 500 internal server error. Error object looks like

```
{
   "statusText": "OK",
   "status": 500,
   "url": "http://localhost:3000/login",
   "ok": false,
   "name": 'HttpErrorResponse',
   "message": "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/login: 500 OK",
   ...
}
```

How I make build is

1. `ionic build --prod --release`
2. `ionic cordova platform remove ios` (if platform already exist).
3. `ionic cordova platform add ios`
4. `ionic cordova prepare ios`

Then I open the same `ios` folder into Xcode, select the developer account, connect my iPad and run it.

Comment: Its more like a Server Issue. try to hit your API via Postman. 
Also try to send you data as JSON format.

Comment: I've mentioned above that same POST call is working in web as well as in android.

Comment: problem I'm facing in making POST call in iOS.

Comment: Please Post your Errors.

Comment: looks like you didn't go through the question properly, I have mentioned the error object also which I'm getting while making a POST request

Comment: Check safari dev tools with network tab

Answer (score 1):

Were you able to resolve it?
I faced similar situation and here's how I got around it.
In capacitor.config.json file we need to specify 'server' from where we are getting the Api data.

```
 "appId": "com.yoursite",
 "appName": "Your Site",
 "bundledWebRuntime": false,
 "npmClient": "npm",
 "webDir": "www",
 "cordova": {},

//This part mentioned below is important.
 "server": {
   "url": "https://yoursite.com",
   "allowNavigation": ["yoursite.com", "*.yoursite.com"]
 },
```

Hope this helps.